# When would I load data from localstorage, for example, when using Ember?

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to wrap my head around Ember.js. I'm just writing a simple app that will need to load some data from local storage. When would I do this? Am I supposed to do this within the `Route`'s `setupController` method? Or, am I supposed to do this in the `Controller`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create Ember.Object that is handler for saving/reading from local storage(has function read(), save(), some properties etc.) and use it as model in Ember.Controller. Then, you might have actions in this controller that call Model's functions, eg. using:

```
this.get('model').getLatestData();
```

Or instead of actions you can use computed properties like this:

```
directory: function() {
        downloadPath = this.get('model.keys').filterBy('Name', 'downloadPath')[0];
        if(downloadPath.Value != '' && downloadPath.Value !== undefined)
            this.get('model').setValue('downloadPath', downloadPath.Value, db);
        this.get('model').getLatestData(db);
        return downloadPath.Value;
    }.property('model.keys.@each.Value')
```

You can see more code [here on GitHub](https://github.com/Kuzirashi/cross-video-downloader/blob/master/app.coffee). I'm using Web Storage, but local storage is simplier.

Comment: I guess this doesn't really clarify anything for me. If I were going to fetch that data, would I do so within the `Route` or the `Controller`? Thanks.

Comment: In the Controller or Controller's Model.